# How to convert Speech(Audio File) To Text in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

**I have Know this question are asking multiple time on SO. Please Review My Question first then put your comments**.

```
We have review below API to convert Speech To Text in iOS. But i am not sure they exactly suitable or not with my requirement. So i am asking there.
1) OpenEars
2) Google API.
3) Speech Recognizer

My Requirement is Below.
1) have the option of recording a new audio file with pause, stop, resume functionality.Here please note that audio file has not limit in size.
2) That Audio File convert into the Text File.

 In this case how to handle this scenario?

 Can you suggest Any Free API or Good API(If Payable)?
 Any Offline API available? (i think it’s not available!)
```

Comment: @Westley, No lick my dear friend!